# grep for multiple regexes, and count the number of occurences

Tags: grep, regular-expression, search, patterns

Say, I have a file, and multiple regexes have to be searched in it and the number of matches for each regex has to be counted.

Thus, I cannot combine the patterns:

```
grep -Po '{regex_1}|{regex_2}|...|{regex_n}' file | wc -l
```

... as the number of occurences for each regex is required.

I obviously could:

```
occurences[i]=$(grep -Po "${regex[i]}" file | wc -l)
```

... but unfortunately, the files encountered may be quite large (> 1 GB) and there are many of patterns (in the range of thousands) to check for, making the process quite slow, as multiple reads of the same file would be involved.

Is there a way to do this in a fast manner?

Comment: Firstly you can share by `grep -e 'regex_1' -e 'regex_2' ...` but much better use `-f` option and put all regexes in a file by 1 line each one.

Comment: with GB we can not expect miracles... Can you tell us some more details about your regex and large file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably `awk` would be fastest shell tool here. You could try:

```
awk "/$regex1/ { ++r1 }
     /$regex2/ { ++r2 }"'
     END { print "regex1:",r1 "\nregex2:",r2 }' <infile
```

Of course if you need to use `perl` regular expressions like your question, then really `perl` is the only answer. However, `awk` does use extended expressions (like `grep -E`) as opposed to basic ones.

Comment: I think you have a perlism (`$`) creeping into your regex's...

Comment: @mr.spuratic, no the idea was that they would be shell variables, hence the double quotes around that section.

Comment: Ah, got it. You could usefully print the regex too.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest solution I can think is **flex**. Following is an untested skeleton:

```
%{
  int count[1000];
%}
%%

regex0  {count[0]++; }
regex1  {count[1]++; }
...
.|\n    {}

%%
int main(){
   yylex();
   // printf the counts;
}
```

flex makes a pretty good job in optimizing the automata and generates fast C code.

You have to recompile it if regexs change...

**EDIT**:
If you implement and try any of the solutions, it would be interesting to see the times.

Answer (score 0):

In case Python is an option, you could first [memory-map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) the file and then run an incremental regex search over it, taking advantage of [named groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) to count pattern occurences. This solution is tolerant of large file sizes

```
from collections import Counter
import re, mmap, contextlib
c = Counter()
with open('data_file', 'r+') as f:
    with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)) as data:
            for m in re.finditer(r'(?P<pat1>regex1)|(?P<pat2>regex2)|(?P<pat3>regex3)',data):
                    c.update(k for (k, v) in m.groupdict().iteritems() if v)

print c.most_common()
[('pat3', 3), ('pat1', 2), ('pat2', 2)]
```